# JSF grid can't be rendered when I use ajax

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I use Primefaces to implement tree and grid. When I click the tree, the grid will change according the node. Now the tree node id can be accepted by java and all of data can be saved in list. But grid data can't change. Does someone has idea about that? Thanks.

```
<p:layoutUnit id="layoutunitleft" position="west" size="360"  resizable="true" collapsible="true" header="Options" minSize="260">
<p:accordionPanel id="accordingpanel1">                         
 <p:tab id="accordingpanel1tab" title="Project">                             
      <!-- <ui:include src="tree.xhtml" />     -->  

  <!--      <h:form id="form">   -->
  <p:tree value="#{treeBean.root}" var="node" id="tree"   dynamic="true" cache="false" selectionMode="single"  selection="#{treeBean.selectedNode}">

    <p:ajax event="expand"  listener="#{treeBean.onNodeExpand}"/>  
    <p:ajax event="collapse"  listener="#{treeBean.onNodeCollapse}" />
    <p:ajax event="select" process=":mainForm:scenarioDetailTable"  listener="#{tableBean.showScenario}" />         
    <p:ajax event="unselect"  listener="#{treeBean.onNodeUnselect}" /> 
    <p:treeNode id="treeNode" expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open" collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed">  
        <h:outputText value="#{node.name}" id="lblNode"/>  
    </p:treeNode>  
</p:tree>     
<!--    </h:form>  -->

 </p:tab>                          
 <p:tab title="Testset">                             
   <h:outputText value="Testset" />                         
 </p:tab>                          
 <p:tab title="Report">                             
  <!--   <h:outputText value="Report" />  -->
   <p:calendar mode="inline" navigator="none"/>                         
 </p:tab>                     
 </p:accordionPanel>                 
</p:layoutUnit>


<!-- grid start --> 
<p:layoutUnit id="layoutunitnorthcenter" position="center" resizable="true" layout="block">            

     <p:dataTable id="scenarioDetailTable" var="scenariob" value="#{tableBean.scenarioDetail}" ajaxRendered="true" >        

        <p:column style="width:20px">  
            <h:outputText id="dragIcon"  
                styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4" />  
            <p:draggable for="dragIcon" revert="true" />  
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="ScenarioName">  
           <h:outputText value="#{scenariob.name}" />  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="Description">  
            <h:outputText value="#{scenariob.description}" size="20"/> 
        </p:column>  

       <p:column headerText="Status">  
           <h:outputText value="#{scenariob.scenarioStatusId}" />  
       </p:column>  

       <p:column headerText="Meta">  
           <h:outputText value="#{scenariob.meta}" /> 
       </p:column>  

       <p:column headerText="Scenario"> 
         <p:graphicImage id="img1" value="/images/logo/images.png"  width="20px" height="20px" style="cursor:pointer" title="Create"/>             
       </p:column>

       <p:column headerText="Step">  
        <h:outputText id="stepIcon"  
                styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-disk" />  
            <p:draggable for="stepIcon" revert="true" /> 
       </p:column>
     </p:dataTable>                      
 </p:layoutUnit>

</p:layout>
</p:layoutUnit>
```

Comment: you mean p:dataTable can't change not DataGrid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following..

```
<p:ajax event="select" 
        update=":mainForm:scenarioDetailTable"  
        listener="#{tableBean.showScenario}" />
```